# Incremental Bootstrapping in Compiler Design

Tags: compiler-construction

I have a question regarding the nature of Incremental Bootstrapping.  Let's say
that I would like to design a bootstrapped compiler for some language.  So I write an initial compiler for a small subset of that language (A) in some other language.
Now I want to extend A to become B (which is closer to the desired language), and I write the compiler for B in A.  My question is:
Should the B compiler compile B to A or B fully?

Essentially:

- B -> A (compiled by A, then the A is then compiled by the initial compiler)

  OR
- B -> target code (compiled completely by A)

Or is there something else entirely that should occur?
I have been looking around for a while and it is still somewhat unclear to me.  Thanks!

Comment: Ever forward!!! Each generation should increase the capability and features from the previous version so no need to get back to `A`. That said, I have done the same and I emit LLVM-IR from my front end and let LLVM take care of all the backend machine code generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the B compiler produce target code unless there is a very good reason not to. There is very little point in making the B compiler generate A, but if you want a quick way to make a compiler that compiles for many different target platforms you could consider generating C code as an intermediate step since then your compiler targets any system that has a C compiler. You could also consider generating Java byte-code or LLVM-IR.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these options makes sense. Compilers compile to some form of object code, not to source code, and a compiler doesn't need another compiler to do that.

Compiler B should compile to executable object code.

Comment: When I see compiled completely or fully, I mean compiled to executable object code. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: Where? By What?

Comment: It's all unclear. Your 'Where? By What?' questions are meaningless.

Comment: @FrankC. 'Subjective' is a strange term to use about a statement you disagree with. The question, and my answer, are about compilers, not transpilers.

Comment: @EJP Yes, I removed the comment. I can't remember the context I had been thinking of when written.